# datepicker class not adding when selected

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I have been trying to add a class for selectable dates. And following is done to add a class

```
$('a.ui-state-default').addClass('myClass');
$('a.ui-state-highlight').removeClass('myClass');

$(".myClass").attr("style", "background:"+background_button+" !important; color:"+text_button+" !important;");
```

This is working fine.

But when I select a date in `datepicker`, it's again reverting back to normal style and the added class to `ui-state-default` is not coming.

Comment: try to provide jsfiddle for the same

Comment: when is this class added... and what do you do when a date is selected

Comment: I have a inline datepicker and for each date we have class called "ui-state-default", So I add another class called "myClass" which is custom to add my css dynamically. So  the problem is initially datepicker is showing myClass for the dates, but when I select any date, it's refreshing and showing normal datepicker. where I don't see my css

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/o7qew84a/ ?

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/01657zgxf3

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a457zgyab

Comment: @user3378428 or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/o7qew84a/2/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the dom for the datepicker is redrawn many times, as you are applying the style only once after the redraw is will be lost.

The solution is to use css classes and [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) callback to style the dates

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var array = [];
  $('#dp').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd M yy',
    beforeShowDay: function(dt) {
      return [1, 'my-style-class']
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.my-style-class a.ui-state-default:not(.ui-state-highlight) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dp"></div>
```

Comment: When I would like to add style dynamically to the class, it's not working, if it's a static class, it comes fine.
like: 
$(".myClass a.ui-state-default").attr("style", "background:"+background_button+" !important; color:"+text_button+" !important;");